# julia floating point compare for zero

Tags: julia

```
julia> r
3×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 -1.77951  -0.79521   -2.57472
  0.0       0.630793   0.630793
  0.0       0.0       -1.66533e-16

julia> sort(abs(diag(r)))[1]
1.6653345369377348e-16

julia> isequal(floor(sort(abs(diag(r)))[1]),0)
true
```

**But this is not right**

```
julia> isequal(sort(abs(diag(r)))[1],convert(AbstractFloat,0.0))
false
```

Is there a function in Julia to check for floating point equivalent to zero?

Comment: Obligatory reference: [What every computer scientist should know about floating point arithmetic](http://www.validlab.com/goldberg/paper.pdf)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`-1.66533e-16` is *not* equivalent to zero. It is, however, *approximately* equivalent to zero (with respect to a particular tolerance), and julia does provide just such a function:

```
isapprox(1e-16, 0.0; atol=1e-15, rtol=0)
```

**edit:** or as Chris pointed out, a good choice for `atol` is `eps()` which corresponds to machine precision for that particular type:

```
julia> isapprox(1e-20, 0.0; atol=eps(Float64), rtol=0)
true
```

Do read the description for `isapprox` to see what the default arguments mean, and to see if you prefer an "absolute" or "relative" tolerance approach (or a mixed approach). Though for a comparison to zero specifically, using an absolute tolerance is fine and probably more intuitive.

Comment: and `eps(T)` is also really helpful for knowing machine epsilon for the number type `T`.

Comment: @Userdijkstra And there are also binary operators `≈` and `≉`, calling `isapprox` with default arguments.

Comment: Just want to point out that `eps(T)`is the precision at the value `one(T)` for type `T`. It's not a universal precision for any type of float. `eps(1.0)` and `eps(2.0)` are different, for example.

Comment: Key point is that values in arrays are printed with less precision, so values close to zero look like they are actually zero.